# Combine 2 arrays based on one value - PHP

Tags: php

I'm creating a form that displays a list of buildings with their associated energy meters.

Some buildings may have multiple meters where as some may only have 1.

```
Array1 = [
'building_name'=>'one house', 
'meter_number'=>'1111',
'meter_type'=>'gas'
]

Array2 = [
'building_name'=>'one house', 
'meter_number'=>'2222',
'meter_type'=>'electricity'
]

Array3 = [
'building_name'=>'two house', 
'meter_number'=>'3333',
'meter_type'=>'gas'
]
```

How do I combine arrays together if they both share the same building name like this?:

```
Array1 = [
'building_name'=>'one house', 
'meter_number'=>'1111',
'meter_type'=>'gas'
'meter_number'=>'2222',
'meter_type'=>'electricity'
]
```

So I would end up with multiple meters under one building.

Apologies if this is a bit unclear, this is my first time posting here.

Comment: You can't get that result as key names must be unique https://3v4l.org/umcHL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys need to be unique in arrays.  So you can't get to what you desire.

However you can group by building name.

```
<?php

$meter1 = [
    'building_name'=>'one house', 
    'meter_number'=>'1111',
    'meter_type'=>'gas'
];

$meter2 = [
    'building_name'=>'one house', 
    'meter_number'=>'2222',
    'meter_type'=>'electricity'
];

$meter3 = [
    'building_name'=>'two house', 
    'meter_number'=>'3333',
    'meter_type'=>'gas'
];


$meters = [$meter1, $meter2, $meter3];

foreach($meters as $meter) {
    $building_meters[$meter['building_name']][] = $meter;
}

var_export($building_meters);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'one house' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'building_name' => 'one house',
      'meter_number' => '1111',
      'meter_type' => 'gas',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'building_name' => 'one house',
      'meter_number' => '2222',
      'meter_type' => 'electricity',
    ),
  ),
  'two house' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'building_name' => 'two house',
      'meter_number' => '3333',
      'meter_type' => 'gas',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use iterators:

```
$iterator = new AppendIterator();
$iterator->append(new ArrayIterator(['foo' => 1]));
$iterator->append(new ArrayIterator(['foo' => 2]));

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
}
```